# Phonegap и консоль разработчика

Tags: phonegap

Пишу приложение на phonegap. И так как основной код - javascript, хотелось бы иметь консоль.
Как в Эклипсе можно посмотреть консоль выполнения программы?

Comment: Погуглил и из всего прочитанного понравилось это:  
http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку фонгап - это обертка для запуска приложений хтмл/цсс/жаваскрипт, то почему бы просто не запускать все это дело без эклипса в том же хроме и жать Ф12 для поиска затыков?..
Ну а потом уже экспортировать через фонгап в .апк

Comment: код в браузере не работает, т.к. использую аппаратуру смартфона (GPS, sqlite)